# Como ingresar una subconsulta en laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo esta consulta en mysql

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT COUNT(id_team_local) FROM seasons WHERE id_team_local = teams.id) AS 'Partidos Jugados' FROM teams
```

y quisiera ingresarla a laravel alguna idea de como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Miguel, por favor cuéntanos qué has intentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que no especificas si estás usando Eloquent o si hay modelos relacionados, voy a dar un ejemplo accediendo directamente la base de datos por medio del facade (DB) y el query builder:

```
$teams = DB::table('teams')
    ->select(DB::raw('id, name, (SELECT COUNT(id_team_local) FROM seasons WHERE id_team_local = teams.id) AS 'Partidos jugados'))
    ->get();
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Comment: Hola intento llenar una tabla de resultados de futbol, es decir Puntos, partidos jugados, goles a favor etc, Tengo la tabla positions, tabla teams y tabla seasons. En positions tengo id de team y en seasons tambien tengo id de team. Estoy usando eloquent